# How do you solve an inequality that involves factorials?

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion, factorial

I have this inequality that's part of a larger problem (regarding Taylor expansions). I have the steps to the solution, but I don't understand this part:

Step 1: $e/1000 > 1/(n+1)!$

Step 2: $1000/e < (n+1)!$

Step 3: $(n+1) = 6$

I'm lost on how that's true? How do you go from step 2 to step 3?

Comment: Actually you can't go to step 3 directly from step 2. $n$ can be any large number. Step 3 should say $(n+1)\geq 6.$

Comment: Adding on to @subrosar 's comment, it is only true for integer values for n+1, as that is the domain of the factorial function, so a simple guess and check is enough to find you integer bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Maths SX! Everyone knows (at least) that $5!=120$, hence  $6!=720$. On the other hand, $2<\mathrm e <4$, so
$$\frac{1000}4=250<\frac{1000}{\mathrm e}<\frac{1000}2=500,$$
so the first factorial  greater than $\frac{1000}{\mathrm e}$ is indeed $6!$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you just use a calculator (or a table of values) to try small values of $n$ and see when the inequality is satisfied. For example, using a calculator, we know that $\dfrac{1000}{e} \approx 367.88$. Also, it is pretty easy to verify that 
\begin{align}
5! = 120 < \dfrac{1000}{e} < 720 = 6!
\end{align}
Hence, we choose $(n+1) = 6$; in other words $n=5$ is the smallest integer value of $n$ which satisfies the inequality
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1000}{e} > \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}
\end{align}

---

In fact any positive integer $n \geq 5$ also satisfies the inequality above, so strictly speaking, we should say $n \geq 5$, not just $n=5$

Comment: Ah, ok, that makes much more sense.  Thanks for taking the time to write it all out!

Comment: @Stephanie You're welcome, but I was initially slightly sloppy; take note of my additional remark about $n \geq 5$.